# retrieve employee and his supervisor information + LDAP +asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ldap

I am working in an ASP.NET internal web project which should displays Employee, his supervisor name.
I have tried to do the same with LDAP using searchQueries but it returned only employee information and did not return manager/supervisor information.
Please do the needful of retrieving manager/supervisor information just like Outlook ( which able to retrieve all records).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read an attribute called "manager", where you can get the distinguished name of the user's manager. For example,

"CN=John,OU=Users,OU=Corporate,DC=Domain,DC=com"

To get the manager's object and obtain its properties you would need to create a new query to LDAP e.g.

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://domain/CN=John,OU=Users,...";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);
string cn = (string)de.Properties["name"].Value;
```